# Get default directory view in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

When you start a new project in Android Studio, your side directory looks like this:[image]

But my directory, looks like this after i needed to access a file outside of /app: [image]

**How i get back to this cleaner looking directory?**

Comment: in the top of your image there is a dropdown written "Project", switch back to "Android"

Answer (score 1):

Click on Project View type. In you're 2nd picture it shows **Project** so just click on it and it will provide you drop-down. So just Select **Android** for 1st picture view

[image: View of Project]

Comment: Please don't accept this as answer because this is what Gustavo wants to tell you